# EF Core QueryExpressionInterceptor for DayOfWeek

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

We had an existing application using ASP.NET MVC and EF6. We migrated to ASP.NET Core and EF Core 7. As title suggests, we are having trouble with existing queries where `DayOfWeek` is used. `DayOfWeek` cannot be translated to equivalent SQL query by EF Core. I cannot modify the code/query as the LINQ queries are generated by DevExtreme Dashboards and they said they cannot fix their code at the moment.

In dashboard we use date fields and assign grouping interval to those which can be DayOfWeek, Date-Hour, etc. The LINQ translation for these functions are not compatible with the EF Core. And as we dont have access to their code, it's not possible for us to modify how it's generating these queries.

On further investigation I ended up reading on `QueryExpressionInterceptor` in EF Core 7. Now my issue is, how do I translate all usage of `DayOfWeek` into something (`DateDiff`) that EF Core can translate to a SQL query.

Thanks to `@Svyatoslav Danyliv` I was able to resolve multiple issues.

Comment: `DayOfWeek` is an `enum` - and T-SQL supports it via `DATEPART` - there is no need to use `DATEDIFF` here at all (you also need to be careful with `SET DATEFIRST` too).

Comment: @Dai but how to use DatePart via QueryExpressionInterceptor? I have looked through other posts on StakcOverflow where they created DatePart method in Context and class and created the expression using HasDBFucntion in OnModelCreating. But my issue is how do I apply that to query?

Comment: Let's start from the top - what happens _normally_? Do you get an exception or does it just generate bad SQL?

Comment: Just exception that it cannot be translated to SQL Query.

Comment: Do you have any way of seeing the Linq `Expression<>` tree or `IQueryable<T>` (i.e. in your code) before EF tries to generate SQL?

Comment: Query is pretty simple as below:

var query = Orders.GroupBy(o => o.OrderDate.DayOfWeek);

and throws the following error:

The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Order>().GroupBy(o => o.OrderDate.DayOfWeek)' could not be translated. 

This is from LinqPad, but DevExtreme dashboards are generating similar queries and failing because of DayOfWeek Property on DateTime field.

Comment: EF's git repo has some [discussion including workarounds](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10404#issuecomment-817292430) about this.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang Thanks. I have already been through those. One can use that workaround if they are creating query manually in code. Here DevExtreme is generating the query with DayOfWeek, hence I am trying to see if I can use Interceptor to manipulate the DayOfWeek.

Comment: @VDWWD, any good reason for closing this question? Answer can be helpful not only for OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented universal extension which replaces any Member or Method by appropriate pattern. It can be useful if you need to support other members translation.

Configure your db context in the following way with `UseMemberReplacement` and `HasDbFunction`. Sample has two replacements: `DateTime.DayOfWeek` and `DateTime.AddHours`.
`DateTime.AddHours` substitution solves issue with date conversions for SQL Server.

```cs
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        // We add AddHours Method replacement to call function DayOfWeekImpl.
        optionsBuilder.UseMemberReplacement((DateTime d) => d.DayOfWeek,
            d => (DayOfWeek)(DayOfWeekImpl(d) - 1));

        // We add DayOfWeek method replacement to call function DateAddHoursImpl.
        optionsBuilder.UseMemberReplacement((DateTime d, double hours) => d.AddHours(hours),
            (d, hours) => DateAddHoursImpl(d, hours));
    }

    static int DayOfWeekImpl(DateTime date) => (int)date.DayOfWeek;

    static DateTime DateAddHoursImpl(DateTime date, double hours) => date.AddHours(hours);

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ... // other model configuring code

        // register 'DayOfWeekImpl' translation code
        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => DayOfWeekImpl(default))
            .HasTranslation(args =>
                new SqlFunctionExpression("DATEPART",
                    new[] { new SqlFragmentExpression("weekday"), args[0] },
                    false,
                    new[] { false, false, false },
                    typeof(int),
                    null
                ));

        // register 'DateAddHoursImpl' translation code
        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => DateAddHoursImpl(default, default))
            .HasTranslation(args =>
                new SqlFunctionExpression("DATEADD",
                    new[]
                    {
                        new SqlFragmentExpression("hour"), args[1], new SqlFunctionExpression("CONVERT",
                            new[] { new SqlFragmentExpression("datetime"), args[0] }, false,
                            new[] { true, false }, typeof(DateTime), RelationalTypeMapping.NullMapping)
                    },
                    false,
                    new[] { false, false, false },
                    typeof(DateTime),
                    null
                ));
    }
}
```

Testing code:

```cs
var query = ctx.AnyTable
    .Select(x => new
        {
            Date = DateTime.Today,
            DayOfWeek = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek,
            HourPlus = DateTime.Today.AddHours(1),
        });

var result = query.First();

if (result.Date.DayOfWeek != result.DayOfWeek)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Something wrong with 'DATEFIRST', check current setting in database 'SELECT @@DATEFIRST'");
```

It should generate the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) 
    CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AS [Date], 
    CAST((DATEPART(weekday, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) - 1) AS int) AS [DayOfWeek],
    DATEADD(hour, 1.0E0, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))) AS [HourPlus]
FROM [AnyTable] AS [e]
```

And extension implementation itself:

```cs
public static class EFCoreLinqExtensions
{
    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseMemberReplacement<TValue>(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, Expression<Func<TValue>> whatToReplace, Expression<Func<TValue>> replacement)
    {
        AddMemberReplacement(optionsBuilder, whatToReplace, replacement);
        return optionsBuilder;
    }

    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseMemberReplacement<TObject, TValue>(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, Expression<Func<TObject, TValue>> whatToReplace, Expression<Func<TObject, TValue>> replacement)
    {
        AddMemberReplacement(optionsBuilder, whatToReplace, replacement);
        return optionsBuilder;
    }

    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseMemberReplacement<TParam1, TParam2, TResult>(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, 
        Expression<Func<TParam1, TParam2, TResult>> whatToReplace, 
        Expression<Func<TParam1, TParam2, TResult>> replacement)
    {
        AddMemberReplacement(optionsBuilder, whatToReplace, replacement);
        return optionsBuilder;
    }

    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseMemberReplacement<TParam1, TParam2, TParam3, TResult>(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, 
        Expression<Func<TParam1, TParam2, TParam3, TResult>> whatToReplace, 
        Expression<Func<TParam1, TParam2, TParam3, TResult>> replacement)
    {
        AddMemberReplacement(optionsBuilder, whatToReplace, replacement);
        return optionsBuilder;
    }

    static void AddMemberReplacement(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, LambdaExpression whatToReplace, LambdaExpression replacement)
    {
        var coreExtension = optionsBuilder.Options.GetExtension<CoreOptionsExtension>();

        QueryExpressionReplacementInterceptor? currentInterceptor = null;
        if (coreExtension.Interceptors != null)
        {
            currentInterceptor = coreExtension.Interceptors.OfType<QueryExpressionReplacementInterceptor>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if (currentInterceptor == null)
        {
            currentInterceptor = new QueryExpressionReplacementInterceptor();
            optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(currentInterceptor);
        }

        MemberInfo member;

        if (whatToReplace.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)
        {
            member = memberExpression.Member;
        }
        else
        if (whatToReplace.Body is MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
        {
            member = methodCallExpression.Method;
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Expression '{whatToReplace.Body}' is not MemberExpression or MethodCallExpression");

        if (whatToReplace.Parameters.Count != replacement.Parameters.Count) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Replacement Lambda should have exact count of parameters as input expression '{whatToReplace.Parameters.Count}' but found {replacement.Parameters.Count}");

        currentInterceptor.AddMemberReplacement(member, replacement);
    }

    class MemberReplacementVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly List<(MemberInfo member, LambdaExpression replacenment)> _replacements;

        public MemberReplacementVisitor(List<(MemberInfo what, LambdaExpression replacenmet)> replacements)
        {
            _replacements = replacements;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            foreach (var (what, replacement) in _replacements)
            {
                if (node.Member == what)
                {
                    var args = new List<Expression>();

                    if (node.Expression != null)
                        args.Add(node.Expression);

                    var visitor = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(replacement.Parameters, args);
                    var newNode = visitor.Visit(replacement.Body);

                    return Visit(newNode);
                }
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            foreach (var (what, replacement) in _replacements)
            {
                if (node.Method == what)
                {
                    var args = new List<Expression>(node.Arguments);
                    if (node.Object != null)
                        args.Insert(0, node.Object);

                    var visitor = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(replacement.Parameters, args);
                    var newNode = visitor.Visit(replacement.Body);

                    return Visit(newNode);
                }
            }

            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }

    }

    sealed class QueryExpressionReplacementInterceptor : IQueryExpressionInterceptor
    {
        readonly List<(MemberInfo member, LambdaExpression replacenment)> _memberReplacements = new();

        public Expression QueryCompilationStarting(Expression queryExpression, QueryExpressionEventData eventData)
        {
            if (_memberReplacements.Count == 0)
                return queryExpression;

            var visitor = new MemberReplacementVisitor(_memberReplacements);

            var result = visitor.Visit(queryExpression);

            return result;
        }

        public void AddMemberReplacement(MemberInfo member, LambdaExpression replacement)
        {
            _memberReplacements.Add((member, replacement));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. You are a life saver. :-). Works exactly as I wanted it to.

Comment: Can we use UseMemberReplacement to replace the implementation of DateTime.AddHours() as well?

Comment: Well, we can, nothing special here. Give me a half of an hour.

Comment: This is what final output I am expecting: 

DATEADD(hour, CAST(CAST(DATEPART(hour, SomeDateField) AS float) AS int), SomeDateField)

Or may be it doesn't matter. Note sure.

Comment: EF Core supports `DateTime.AddHours` what is the problem? `Hour` and `DayOfWeek` is different thing. Which LINQ query you have?

Comment: My issue is DevExtreme dashboard generating this queries and I have no way to manipulate those. For some reason it is generating the query that casts datetime to date. DATEADD(hour, CAST(CAST(DATEPART(hour, SomeDateField) AS float) AS int), CONVERT(date, SomeDateField)). Now this throws error when it's executed in sql. So I want to prevent that extra cast to date.

Comment: Ah I see, looks like EF Core failed to generate correct SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255361/discussion-between-dharmesh-tailor-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).

Comment: Your updated code for MethodCall works as expected. Thanks once again.