# Writing custom Entity Framework function with IMethodCallTranslator

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a query that looks something like this.

```cs
var railcars = DbContext.Railcars
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Number = r.RailcarNumber,
        Quantity = railcar.InboundQuantity
            - DbContext.Transfers
                .Where(t => t.FromType == TransferType.Railcar && t.FromId == railcar.Id)
                .Sum(t => t.Quantity)
            + DbContext.Transfers
                .Where(t => t.ToType == TransferType.Railcar && t.ToId == railcar.Id)
                .Sum(t => t.Quantity)
    };
```

The calculation for the `Quantity` is a little convoluted, and I will use this calculation in many different places. So I was looking to simplify this syntax a little. What I would really like to do is create my own function and make it convertible to SQL something like the following.

```cs
public static class QueryHelper
{
    public static double GetCurrentQuantity(this Railcar railcar, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("This method cannot be executed directly.");
    }
}

var railcars = DbContext.Railcars
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Number = r.RailcarNumber,
        Quantity = QueryHelper.GetCurrentQuantity(r, DbContext)
    };
```

I've been looking into using `IMethodCallTranslator` to translate the needed code to SQL. But the only examples I can find seem old and, for example, the call signature for `IMethodCallTranslator.Translate()` was completely different.

Also, I'm not sure how to go about creating an expression as complex as I need into a `SqlExpression` (which is what the `Translate()` method returns).

Questions:

1. Does anyone know if it's possible? Am I on the right track?
2. Are there any good examples of this?
3. Any examples or documentation on building a `SqlExpression` this complex?
4. Any examples for my specific logic to help get me started?

Comment: Personally, I'd move the logic to a `VIEW` or TVF, then load the `VIEW` in a 1-liner in EF.

Comment: _"Is this possible?"_ - Yes, it's "possible", but you'll have to do a _lot_ of plumbing and interception work and even then I can't promise it will be reliably re-composable - which is also why I feel this logic belongs in a DB object (like a view or function) instead of trying to fight EF's query generator.

Comment: @Dai: A view isn't what I want. I will have many variations on this query. I'm just trying to simplify the syntax. A view will not have that type of flexibility. Currently looking into `IMethodCallTranslator`.

Comment: Read this article, it's simple: https://dev.to/timur_kh/ef-core-6-custom-functions-with-dbfunctionattribute-1bb3. Basically you create a stored procedure, that do what you want, then you decorate your property with the `DbFunction()` Attribute. Now you can simply call that in a LINQ query.

Comment: @PoulBak You can't call a `PROCEDURE` from a query, I think you meant a `FUNCTION`.

Comment: @PoulBak: My goal is to incorporate it into a single query.

Comment: @Dai: You're right, typo.

Comment: @JonathanWood a view is the *correct* solution *and* what you need. You're talking about reusing a SQL expression, not an application method. Databases aren't implementation details and bad queries can have a big impact is scalability, even correctness. You'll need the generated SQL simply to debug or tune your code anyway. `My goal is to incorporate it into a single query` that's what a view or a computed column do. A computed column can be *persisted* too, which means you won't have to pay the calculation cost on every row access.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm looking for ways to duplicate my initial query, in much the same way the `EF.Functions` functions work. How do you a view with different `WHERE` clauses, `JOIN`s and other variations like that? It doesn't seem like it would work. But if you have a link showing how it would work, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: @JonathanWood they don't work that way. They're only placeholders that get mapped to specific SQL functions

Comment: You can use views almost anywhere a table would be used which means WHERE and JOIN can be used without problem. Even modifications (Update, Insert,Delete) are possible with restrictions. You can map entities to views with `ToView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve that is by adding a third-party extension that corrects the expression tree before passing it to the LINQ Translator. I would suggest using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).

If you are using EF Core, there are configuration extensions that enable expression expanding. You can achieve this by adding the following code to your project:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString) // or any other provider
    .WithExpressionExpanding();     // enabling LINQKit extension
```

For EF6, you can use the extension method `AsExpandable()` to achieve similar functionality. Simply add this call at the top of your query:

```cs
var result = query.AsExpandable()
    .ToList();
```

With LINQKit, you can mark your methods with the `ExpandableAttribute` and specify a static function that returns an expression representation for injection into the query. Here's an example:

```cs
public static class QueryHelper
{
    [Expandable(nameof(GetCurrentQuantityImpl))]
    public static double GetCurrentQuantity(this Railcar railcar, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("This method cannot be executed directly.");
    }

    static Expression<Func<Railcar, ApplicationDbContext, double>> GetCurrentQuantityImpl()
    {
        return (railcar, dbContext) => railcar.InboundQuantity
            - dbContext.Transfers
                .Where(t => t.FromType == TransferType.Railcar && t.FromId == railcar.Id)
                .Sum(t => t.Quantity)
            + dbContext.Transfers
                .Where(t => t.ToType == TransferType.Railcar && t.ToId == railcar.Id)
                .Sum(t => t.Quantity);
    }
}
```

After defining this method, you can use `GetCurrentQuantity` in your LINQ queries.

---

### Without LINQKit

For those who cannot use third-party extensions, there is an extract from LINQKit that does the same thing:

**ExpandableAttribute**

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class ExpandableAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates instance of attribute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodName">Name of method in the same class that returns substitution expression. [Optional]</param>
    public ExpandableAttribute(string methodName = null)
    {
        MethodName = methodName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of method in the same class that returns substitution expression.
    /// </summary>
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
}
```

**Extension realization:**

```cs
public static class EFCoreLinqExtensions
{
    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseMemberReplacement(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var coreExtension = optionsBuilder.Options.GetExtension<CoreOptionsExtension>();

        QueryExpressionReplacementInterceptor? currentInterceptor = null;
        if (coreExtension.Interceptors != null)
        {
            currentInterceptor = coreExtension.Interceptors.OfType<QueryExpressionReplacementInterceptor>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if (currentInterceptor == null)
        {
            currentInterceptor = new QueryExpressionReplacementInterceptor();
            optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(currentInterceptor);
        }

        return optionsBuilder;
    }

    private sealed class MemberReplacementVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly Dictionary<MemberInfo, LambdaExpression?> _expandableCache = new();

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (GetExpandLambda(node.Member, out var methodLambda))
            {
                var newExpr = methodLambda.Parameters.Count > 0
                    ? ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(methodLambda.Parameters[0], node.Expression!,
                        methodLambda.Body)
                    : methodLambda.Body;

                return Visit(newExpr);
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (GetExpandLambda(node.Method, out var methodLambda))
            {
                Expression newExpr;
                if (node.Method.IsStatic)
                {
                    var replaceVisitor = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(methodLambda.Parameters, node.Arguments);

                    if (node.Arguments.Count != methodLambda.Parameters.Count)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(
                            $"Required {node.Arguments.Count} arguments, but returned lambda with {methodLambda.Parameters.Count} parameters during call {node.Method}");

                    newExpr = replaceVisitor.Visit(methodLambda.Body);
                }
                else
                {
                    List<Expression> replacements = new(methodLambda.Parameters.Count);

                    replacements.Add(node.Object!);
                    replacements.AddRange(node.Arguments);

                    if (replacements.Count != methodLambda.Parameters.Count)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(
                            $"Required {replacements.Count} arguments, but returned lambda with {methodLambda.Parameters.Count} parameters during call {node.Method}");

                    var replaceVisitor = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(methodLambda.Parameters, replacements);
                    newExpr = replaceVisitor.Visit(methodLambda.Body);
                }

                return Visit(newExpr);
            }

            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }

        #region Helper methods

        static bool IsNullableType(Type type)
        {
            return !type.IsValueType || type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
        }

        static object? EvaluateExpression(Expression? expr)
        {
            if (expr == null)
                return null;

            switch (expr.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Default:
                    return !IsNullableType(expr.Type) ? Activator.CreateInstance(expr.Type) : null;

                case ExpressionType.Constant:
                    return ((ConstantExpression)expr).Value;

                case ExpressionType.Convert:
                case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
                {
                    var unary = (UnaryExpression)expr;
                    var operand = EvaluateExpression(unary.Operand);
                    if (operand == null)
                        return null;
                    break;
                }

                case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                {
                    var member = (MemberExpression) expr;

                    if (member.Member.IsFieldEx())
                        return ((FieldInfo)member.Member).GetValue(EvaluateExpression(member.Expression));

                    if (member.Member is PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
                    {
                        var obj = EvaluateExpression(member.Expression);
                        if (obj == null)
                        {
                            if (propertyInfo.IsNullableValueMember())
                                return null;
                            if (propertyInfo.IsNullableHasValueMember())
                                return false;
                        }
                        return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
                    }

                    break;
                }

                case ExpressionType.Call:
                {
                    var mc = (MethodCallExpression)expr;
                    var arguments = mc.Arguments.Select(EvaluateExpression).ToArray();
                    var instance  = EvaluateExpression(mc.Object);

                    if (instance == null && mc.Method.IsNullableGetValueOrDefault())
                        return null;

                    return mc.Method.Invoke(instance, arguments);
                }
            }

            var value = Expression.Lambda(expr).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
            return value;
        }

        bool GetExpandLambda(MemberInfo memberInfo, out LambdaExpression expandLambda)
        {
            if (_expandableCache.TryGetValue(memberInfo, out expandLambda))
            {
                return expandLambda != null;
            }

            var canExpand = memberInfo.DeclaringType != null;
            if (canExpand)
            {
                // shortcut for standard methods
                canExpand = memberInfo.DeclaringType != typeof(Enumerable) &&
                            memberInfo.DeclaringType != typeof(Queryable);
            }

            if (canExpand)
            {
                if (memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExpandableAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() is ExpandableAttribute attr && memberInfo.DeclaringType != null)
                {
                    var methodName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.MethodName) ? memberInfo.Name : attr.MethodName;

                    Expression expr;

                    if (memberInfo is MethodInfo method && method.IsGenericMethod)
                    {
                        var args = method.GetGenericArguments();

                        expr = Expression.Call(memberInfo.DeclaringType, methodName, args);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        expr = Expression.Call(memberInfo.DeclaringType, methodName, Type.EmptyTypes);
                    }

                    expandLambda = (EvaluateExpression(expr) as LambdaExpression)!;
                    if (expandLambda == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(
                            $"Expandable method from '{memberInfo.DeclaringType}.{methodName}()' have returned not a LambdaExpression.");
                    }

                    _expandableCache.Add(memberInfo, expandLambda);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            _expandableCache.Add(memberInfo, null);

            return false;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    sealed class QueryExpressionReplacementInterceptor : IQueryExpressionInterceptor
    {
        public Expression QueryCompilationStarting(Expression queryExpression, QueryExpressionEventData eventData)
        {
            var visitor = new MemberReplacementVisitor();

            var result = visitor.Visit(queryExpression);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

For initializing extension, it is needed to call `UseMemberReplacement()` method in `OnConfiguring` method of `DbContext` class:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString) // or any other provider
    .UseMemberReplacement();        // enabling extension
```

Comment: Try before judging. I can replicate this functionality using just EF Core and interceptors, but it will be almost copy/paste from existing LINQKit functionality. LINQKit is VERY simple addition to EF Core. If it will work for you, i’ll replicate this easily by just interceptor.

Comment: As I know LINQ translation (almost decade), it is bad idea and very complicated. Translation as `EF.Functions` requires a lot of manipulations and `SqlSelectExpression` involving. Anyway try. BTW, few days ago [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77148925/10646316) with replacing any function by `HasDbFunction` translation (very similar to your needs).  Look at this closer, maybe it is your solution.

Comment: `IMethodCallTranslator` needs service replacement, but here we just replace in Expression Tree one function by another via interceptor. If you want to play with `SqlExpression` you need to dig into EF Core underneath very deeply. Probably it is possible but it do not worth my efforts.

Comment: I was able to get this working exactly as I want. Thanks. It's too bad Entity Framework can't handle this. My two concerns are still that it's yet another third-party dependency. And also that I noticed LINQKit has many versions for different versions of .NET. This last issue suggests that LINQKit is likely to break whenever I upgrade .NET.

Comment: It has so many versions because it supports a tons of legacy to do not break anything. Also because EF Core in major versions may break compatibility, usually in interception API. Library takes handle of this. For sure you can create your implementation, but such supporting goes to your hands. So, if it works for you, we can get rid of LINQKit.

Comment: I would be very curious how much code is required to implement just the functionality I need, and how much that would be likely to break with new .NET versions. If it wasn't a ton of code, then getting rid of LINQKit would be ideal.

Comment: Here we go. Added non LINQKit solution.

Comment: Thanks. Please give me some time to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something like that should be possible by building the Fn to execute in the query.

```
private Func<Railcar, int> BuildQuantity(AppDbContext context)
{
   return (Railcar r) => {
       return context.Transfers.Where(t => t.TransferToType == "RC" && t.TransferToId == r.RailcarId)
           .Sum(t => t.Quantity)
       - context.Transfers.Where(t => t.TransferFromType == "RC" && t.TransferFromId == r.RailcarId)
           .Sum(t => t.Quantity); };
}
```

Then when building your query:

```
var query = context.Railcars
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.RailcarId,
        x.Name,
        Quantity = startingQuantity
            + BuildQuantity(context)(x)
     });
```

Passing the DbContext may not be necessary if using a single injected DbContext instance, but if you're using a scoped instance or a UoW pattern then it might be necessary.  You can probably inject the startingQuantity into the method itself as well. I just tested it this far and got the same result as the manual parsing.

Note that I would only recommend running constructs like this across single railcars or small sets. If run across entire sets you could encounter noticeable performance problems as it's sub-querying across the transaction table twice.

**Edit:** Regarding the DbContext instance. If your code looks something like this:

```
public class SomeService
{
    private AppDbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    
    public SomeService(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(dbContext, nameof(dbContext));
        DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void SomeActionWithRailcars()
    {
         var query = context.Railcars
            .Select(x => new
        {
            x.RailcarId,
            x.Name,
            Quantity = startingQuantity
                + BuildQuantity()(x)
        });      
    }
    private Func<Railcar, int> BuildQuantity() {...}
}
```

... then you likely do not need to pass the DbContext into BuildQuantity since it can use the same injected DbContext instance. If instead you are scoping a DbContext within the call where you are building the initial query, whether using

```
using var DbContext = new AppDbContext();
```

or something like a Factory or Unit of Work to instantiate a DbContext then you would want to pass that DbContext instance into the method like the original example. If the method looked more like:

```
private Func<Railcar, int> BuildQuantity()
{
    using var context = new AppDbContext();
    return (Railcar r) => {
        return context.Transfers.Where(t => t.TransferToType == "RC" && t.TransferToId == r.RailcarId)
           .Sum(t => t.Quantity)
        - context.Transfers.Where(t => t.TransferFromType == "RC" && t.TransferFromId == r.RailcarId)
           .Sum(t => t.Quantity); };
}
```

... then this wouldn't work because the this would be attempting to marry up expressions across two different DbContext instances.

Comment: This was actually very similar to the first thing I tried but I could not get the syntax to work. Now I can. I will run some tests. Since the expression needs the database context, I don't know what you mean about not passing that. Perhaps you could elaborate.

Comment: What I had meant is that if you are injecting a DbContext instance into the class where this query is being run, and this method has access to the same module-level DbContext then you likely don't need to pass the context into the call, but this example just takes the safe route in case the method doesn't have access to the exact same DbContext instance as the rest of the query expression.

Comment: I see. The method will be part of a static class so it can be used from any query.

Comment: Yep, in that case you would want to pass in the DbContext.

Comment: FYI, I have not been able to get this to work. The issue is the way I pass the `DbContext`. At the time the method is called, there is already an open `DataReader`. And so I get the exception *There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.*

Comment: That sounds like your code is potentially doing something non-conventional with the DbContext which is going to potentially interfere with any solution you try,  Perhaps consider adding the entire operation you are trying to run to the question to see what might be causing that complication, or simplify your solution to use a DbContext instance more naturally. The method I outlined above does work, as I created a basic example with a similar loosely joined transfer OwnerType + OwnerId relationship.

Comment: The only issue here is that, without dedicated foreign key constraints, I have to manually refer to the joining table. And this means accessing the DbContext instance. If it's all written as a single query, it works fine. There is nothing non standard about it. The DBContext passed to `BuildQuantity()` cannot be used during the main query.

Comment: "The DBContext passed to BuildQuantity() cannot be used during the main query. " This does not make sense, the test I ran scoped a DbContext with the main query to select from Railcars where the Quantity calling the static BuildQuantity method passing that context instance in, and it ran without complaint. Perhaps post a complete example with your attempt with the static method. If your example is a simplification of what you are really trying to do it will be impossible to suggest a fix. EF does not normally report open data readers when referenced multiple times within the same query.

Comment: Also, what database / provider is this running against? You may need to enable something like MultipleActiveResultSets  with SQL Server or equivalent. If you are testing against an in-memory database substitute then you might be hitting a limitation of the database engine. Make sure at the end of your statement to fetch the railcars you are materializing the query /w a ToList() or equivalent in case this is tripping MARS.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you did, but I have definitely seen this error before if I use DbContext in a way where it somehow is not seen as the same query. And I'm using SQL Server. Are you saying you ran the code that you posted? It's a little different from mine, but seems mostly the same.

Comment: Ok, I just tested and it is due to MARS.  If you add "MultipleActiveResultsets=True" to your connection string it should work as expected.  I turned off MARS on my connection string (EF generally recommends enabling it by default for SQL Server) and I got the active datareader exception. (edited: MultipleActiveResultsets not AllowMultipleActiveResultsets)

Comment: Strangely when embedding the multiple DbContext references within the single query it works without MARS, but as soon as you extract it to a func<> it trips up on MARS. Not sure if there is a way to make it happy like it is expanded within the query.

Comment: Thanks for isolating that. Of course, I would prefer it to work the same as if I just created a single query. I have it working with LINQKit, and I've made a feature request to Microsoft to make it easier to write custom methods that can be converted to SQL. I still need to decide which approach I take for now.