# Entity Framework Core is failing to retrieve data when I'm trying to call an extension method in the query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When I have the following EF query which is failing to retrieve the data from the db.

```
var results = await (from a in agreements
                        let showPasscode = <snipped>
                        let passcode = <snipped>
                        select new Result(
                            a.Id,
                            a.UserId,
                            a.CurrentCycle().StartsOn,
                            passcode,
                            showPasscode)
                        )
                        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

And the code for `CurrentCyle`

```
public static AgreementCycle CurrentCycle(this Agreement agreement) => 
    agreement.Cycles
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.StartsOn)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now when I run this (and put a breakpoint) in the extension method, I get the following:

[image]

Now I KNOW the database -does- have the linked data, for this item.

I'm *guessing* this might be related to maybe some *delayed* expression handling? Like, extension methods are ran after the db results are executed and the property hasn't been "Included" or something?

If I -manually- add the content of the extension method in, I get the correct result:

```
var results = await (from a in agreements
                        let showPasscode = <snipped>
                        let passcode = <snipped>
                        select new Result(
                            a.Id,
                            a.UserId,
                            a.Cycles.OrderByDescending(c => c.StartsOn).FirstOrDefault().StartsOn, // <-- HERE
                            passcode,
                            showPasscode)
                        )
                        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

So I'm not sure what needs to be done. Now, if this is all about missing 'Include(..)' statements .. this might not work because of the format of my query - it's like it's the old linq-to-sql format. Why? because of those 2x `let` commands. I love those and it is really helping make my query easier/simpler. I'm not sure I can do that in any way?

Comment: Just answered [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77170857/10646316). You cannot define just extension method and expect that EF Core will translate that. `from a in agreements.Include(a => Cycles)` should fix your problem, but query will be ineffective, because all cycles will be loaded.

Comment: Related hint: consider `a.Cycles.Select(x => x.StartsOn).Max()` instead of doing all the orderdescending, firstordefault, member access code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have client side evaluation enabled and do you see any warnings that client-side evaluation is being used with your original query?

Extension methods normally do not work with EF unless you have client-side evaluation turned on since the extension method cannot be transposed down to SQL. I suspect this is a case where you have client side evaluation running but have lazy loading disabled so when the client-side goes to execute against the Cycles, the collection is empty.

This might be resolvable by eager loading the cycles /w `Include(x => x.Cycles)` but that typically isn't ideal since it can enlarge the data footprint size coming back. This might also be resolved with enabling lazy loading but that is almost never a good solution due to performance hits when working with sets.

The manual extraction that you had done is honestly the correct solution. If you want a tidier way of doing that in one place, consider using a Mapper that works with EF's `IQueryable` implementation. This way you can configure how to translate Entity -> Result DTO and the rules around mapping things like the latest StartsOn can reside in the mapping. For example Automapper supports `ProjectTo<TDestination>()`. (https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html)

Comment: Thank you kindly for your kind reply. I really love this part of your answer: "but that typically isn't ideal since it can enlarge the data footprint size coming back". People just don't think _or care_ about this important piece of info, IMO! I'm going to check out what `client-side evaluation` is and if this is impacting things. Finally -> I cannot do  Automapper : ethical and religious reasons 