# Make reusable expressions for Entity Framework queries

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a query that looks something like this.

```
var railcars = DbContext.Railcars
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Number = r.RailcarNumber,
        Quantity = r.InboundQuantity
            - DbContext.Transfers
                .Where(t => t.FromId == r.Id && t.FromType == TransferType.Railcar)
                .Sum(t => t.Quantity)
            + DbContext.Transfers
                .Where(t => t.ToId == r.Id && t.ToType == TransferType.Railcar)
                .Sum(t => t.Quantity)
    }
```

This works, but the expression to calculate `Quantity` is a little convoluted and I need to use that expression in many different queries. So instead I tried to define the query separately.

```
public static class QueryHelper
{
    public static Func<Railcar, double> GetRailcarQuantity(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        return (Railcar r) => r.InboundQuantity
            - dbContext.Transfers
                .Where(t => t.FromId == r.Id && t.FromType == TransferType.Railcar)
                .Sum(t => t.Quantity)
            + dbContext.Transfers
                .Where(t => t.ToId == r.Id && t.ToType == TransferType.Railcar)
                .Sum(t => t.Quantity);
    }
}

var railcars = dbContext.Railcars
    .Where(r => r.FacilityId == UserContext.FacilityId)
    .Select(r => new
    {
        r.RailcarNumber,
        Quantity = QueryHelper.GetRailcarQuantity(dbContext)(r)
    })
    .ToList();
```

This compiles, but when I run it, I get an exception in `GetRailcarQuantity()`.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'

I believe the issue is with how I'm passing `DbContext`. I think it fails because I attempt to use the context when a query is already running. But I don't see how I'd work around this.

Can anyone see a way to separate this calculation so that I can use it in many different queries?

Comment: Consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).

Comment: @NetMage: Yes, this is what everyone seems to be telling me. I was hoping to avoid a third-party solution.

Comment: What's  wrong with answers which I have prepared? You do not understand how they work? I even showed you non LINQKit solution. Have you even tried?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: I'm sorry. I thought I explained that I was hoping to avoid a third-party solution. And yes, I told you I didn't understand how they worked in one of my replies to you. But that is a different issue from wanting to avoid a third-party solution.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: And yes, I would love to use your non-third-party solution. But after working it a while, it seems a little too complex for the expression I needed. In fact, [someone from Microsoft even told me it was not recommended](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31858). So I was looking for a simpler approach. The approach explained here *is* simple but has problems due only to the fact that I need to pass the `DbContext`.

Comment: I will vote for close this issue as duplicate and show how to use `UseMemberReplcement`. Also I have noticed that I can rewrite LINQKit functionality easily, it is similar to `UseMemberReplcement`, but you still want some miracle. What I have proposed is easiest way to accomplish your task.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: I don't think you're listening. The approach I'm asking about in this question (which is different from my other question) is very simple and would work except for the fact that I need a `DbContext`. How is looking for a workaround a miracle? I don't think you're being reasonable now. I'm working with a customer. They have concerns about how many third-party components we add. I have valid reasons to prefer to avoid it.

Comment: 1 ) Try LINQKit !!! 2) If it is OK, we can remove this dependency, it has simple `ExpressionVisitor`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: Well, I was hoping the approach I put in this question would be a simple workaround. But since I'm blocked now, I will try LINQKit and spend some time understanding exactly what it does.

Comment: I does simple thing, replaces MethodCall or MemberAccess by another Expression. It makes resulting LINQ query passed to EF Core enriched with repetitive expressions and as a plus - not written by the hand.

Comment: Do you have a relation defined between Railcars and Transfers ? I see you are avoiding using .Include() in your query, is there a specific reason?

Comment: @david-ao: Yes, we have many different types of containers (silos, warehouses, railcars, trucks, ships, etc.) that we transfer quantities between. It was getting out of hand so we defined a single table for this (Transfers). The trade off is that there is no foreign key constraints because the foreign keys can refer to any container type.

Comment: Actually you are not listening to @SvyatoslavDanyliv, or not even reading the LinqKit link which explains the problem and their solution. It doesn't matter what type of arguments your **custom** method has, `QueryHelper.GetRailcarQuantity` is part of the `Select` **expression tree**, so it will **never** be called. That's why you need expression tree modification helpers which replace such "calls" with the expression from the body of the method, similar to what you could do manually by copy/paste the reusable part to each place you want to use such method. Expression != Func.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing custom Entity Framework function with IMethodCallTranslator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160320/writing-custom-entity-framework-function-with-imethodcalltranslator)