# Reusable Expression with IQueryable in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to create a reusable Expression with an IQueryable (and also int) and input in a LINQ query.

The basic version looks like this and it works fine

```
        Expression<Func<Insurance, int, Insurance>> expressionTest = (ins, i) => ins;
        var compiled = expressionTest.Compile();

        var x = await _ctx.Set<AC>()
            .Where(ac => txIds.Contains(ac.Guid))
            .Select(ac => new
            {
                ac,
                Test = _ctx.Set<Insurance>()
                    .AsQueryable()
                    .Select(f => compiled.Invoke(f, ac.ReportMonthId)).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But I Would like to use the whole Insurance table in my expression for more filtering, so I added an IQueryable in the expression and changed my LINQ query to look like this

```
    Expression<Func<IQueryable<Insurance>, int, Insurance>> expressionTest = (ins, i) => ins.FirstOrDefault();
    var compiled = expressionTest.Compile();

    var x = await _ctx.Set<AC>()
        .Where(ac => txIds.Contains(ac.Guid))
        .Select(ac => new
        {
            ac,
            Test = compiled.Invoke(_ctx.Set<Insurance>().AsQueryable(), ac.ReportMonthId)
        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This however, gives me this error
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Insurance>()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.`

I also changed the int input from using `ac.ReportMonthId` to just `1` in the LINQ Query, and it works. I also tried to materialize the query (ToList) and used that as an input into the expression and that worked as well. So it seems to be something wrong regarding how i use `ac.ReportMonthId` as input in the expression within the LINQ query.

I also tried to return a IQueryable in the expression and materialized it with a `ToList` within the query, with the same error.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Answering similar few times a week: check [new one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77170857/10646316)