# Could I pass function invocation inside Expression's body for EF 6 query C# 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code. I try to pass call to IsActive inside Expression for query's Where clause, but it doesn't execute

```cs
protected Expression<Func<vAccount, bool>> ActiveAccountPredicate => a =>
    (
        IsActive(a)
    )
    && (!a.Foreign || IsShowForeign)
    && (a.RegistrationTypeId != RegistrationType.NotRegistered || IsShowNotRegistered);

public static bool IsActive(vAccount a)
{
    return (a.DepartedDate == null || a.DepartedDate >= DateTime.Now)
            && (a.RegistrationTypeId != RegistrationType.NotRegistered || a.SupoDepartedDate == null || a.SupoDepartedDate >= DateTime.Now)
            && (a.RegistrationTypeId != RegistrationType.NotRegistered || a.RegistrationExpiredDate == null || a.RegistrationExpiredDate >= DateTime.Now);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing custom Entity Framework function with IMethodCallTranslator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160320/writing-custom-entity-framework-function-with-imethodcalltranslator)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `IsActive` as an `Expression` as well.

```cs
public static Expression<Func<vAccount, bool>> IsActive => a =>
{
    return (a.DepartedDate == null || a.DepartedDate >= DateTime.Now)
            && (a.RegistrationTypeId != RegistrationType.NotRegistered || a.SupoDepartedDate == null || a.SupoDepartedDate >= DateTime.Now)
            && (a.RegistrationTypeId != RegistrationType.NotRegistered || a.RegistrationExpiredDate == null || a.RegistrationExpiredDate >= DateTime.Now);
};
```

Then you need to apply it as a separate `Where`

```cs
protected Expression<Func<vAccount, bool>> ActiveAccountPredicate =>
    IsActive
      .Where(a =>
       (!a.Foreign || IsShowForeign)
    && (a.RegistrationTypeId != RegistrationType.NotRegistered || IsShowNotRegistered);
```

Comment: Without LINQKit is also unusable inside other expression.

Comment: I don't think that's true. This should work fine with EF Core.

Comment: I know it is true. If you pass It to just `Where(IsActive)` it will work, but with combination `IsActive(a)  && otherPerdicate`, as in OP question,  it will not compile and will not work without third party extensions.

Comment: OK have edited.