# EFCore 7 reusable expression translation issues on collections

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I have the following piece of projector:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<Order, OrderModel>> ProjectToOrderModel()
    {
        return order => new OrderModel
        {
            Uid = order.Uid,
            Table = ProjectToOrderTableModel(order.Table),
        };
    }

    public static TableModel ProjectToOrderTableModel(Table table) => new()
    {
        Id = table.Id,
        Name = table.Name
    };
```

Where Order is the EFCore entity and OrderModel is a POCO.

Whenever I do the following : db.Orders.Select(Mapper.ProjectToOrderModel())

The correct SQL is generated by using the projection fields and not querying the whole columns.
This surprised me because ProjectToOrderTableModel is a function and not an expression.

However things get confusing when we get into lists. Rewriting the above snippet trying to include a nested collection

```cs
public static Expression<Func<Order, OrderModel>> ProjectToOrderModel()
    {
        return order => new OrderModel
        {
            Uid = order.Uid,
            Table = ProjectToOrderTableModel(order.Table),
            Items = order.OrderItems.AsQueryable().Select(MapToOrderItemsModel).ToList(),
        };
    }

    public static TableModel ProjectToOrderTableModel(Table table) => new()
    {
        Id = table.Id,
        Name = table.Name
    };

    public static OrderItemModel MapToOrderItemsModel(OrderItem i)
    {
         return new()
            {
                Uid = i.Uid,
                Name = i.Title,
                Price = i.Price
            };
    }
```

This fails because the Expression of type System.Func cannot be translated, which makes sense.

I cannot understand how it works for a singular model, but it cannot work on a collection... ? Is there any tracking bug, or is it a forbidden thing to do?!

P.S: I'm aware of the solution of implementing a public static Expression<Func<OrderItem, OrderItemModel>>, I just don't understand why the above doesn't work

Comment: Actually it is obvious. In second variant `MapToOrderItemsModel` is not called but registered in Expression Tree. Then EF Core is trying to translate expression and found this unknown method. Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77170857/10646316), it can help you.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I find it very interesting that in the first snippet `ProjectToOrderTableModel` gets called but in the second snippet it is just registered... I was hoping we can do it without using a library, I guess the only way is to refactor `MapToOrderItemsModel` to be an expression instead.

Comment: It is what compile do for `Expression<Func<,>>` - generates Expression Tree.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I didn't understand you..?

Comment: "Whenever I do the following : db.Orders.Select(Mapper.ProjectToOrderModel()) [...] This surprised me because ProjectToOrderTableModel is a function and not an expression." .. is there a typo? Your example refers to ProjectToOrderModel whereas your expectation refers to ProjectToOrderTableModel.

Comment: @Rubidium37 The snippet ` db.Orders.Select(Mapper.ProjectToOrderModel())` corresponds to the first function that is called in order to convert "Order" -> "OrderModel". This conversion happens in this `ProjectToOrderModel()` function. My misunderstanding is inside that function where I wanna map `OrderItem` -> `OrderItemModel`. Basically the error happens in this line `Items = order.OrderItems.AsQueryable().Select(MapToOrderItemsModel).ToList(),`

Comment: *I was hoping we can do it without using a library* - proposed big answer has solution how do not use library. There is no other ways.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, okay thank you. Can you post your solution as an "answer" so I can mark it.

Comment: I think upvoting answer which I have prepared will be enough.

Comment: @Γιώργος-Τσομλεκτσής
I still think there is a typo: `ProjectToOrderModel` uses `ProjectToOrderTable` and not `ProjectToOrderTableModel` ? Not very important per se, but it confuses me because there should be 2 methods involved in the first example and it is not clear which one works better than expected.

Comment: @Rubidium37 You're right sorry for that. I'm editing my original question

Comment: What's the original query you want to *simplify*? If you have to use `order.OrderItems.AsQueryable().Select(MapToOrderItemsModel).ToList()` in an *expression*, something very weird is going on already. It means `order.OrderIems` and by extension `order` is already loaded into memory.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with these expressions anyway? The attempt to "reuse" may result in far more complex and hard-to-maintain code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They're not already loaded into memory (verified by debugging the SQL statements of EFCore). I'm not exactly trying to reuse it (although this might happen) but right now more of separate the mapping projection logic from the query logic.

Comment: You're doing the opposite right now- trying to indirectly map in the LINQ query itself, wondering what's going on. The `QueryableExtensions.Select` method accepts expressions only and  `AsQueryable().Select(MapToOrderItemsModel)` uses a method group, not a function call. That got translated to an expression. What you try to do can be simplified by using AutoMapper's [Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure I completely follow you but yeah what I'm trying to do is similar to the AutoMapper ProjectTo<>. However I'd like to avoid adding additional dependencies. Also I think automapper is gonna make things more complicated since the database model doesn't correspond 1-1 to my "Model" I'm trying to map. That means I would have to create a profile for each of these entities which would be more verbose of what I'm trying to do "manually" (also for the sake of learning). Plus I don't particularly like Automapper using reflection.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is a runnable snippet of a working example: https://gist.github.com/UltraWelfare/4993a84f06d2b4d1549ba1806920f7b8 (The point of the snippet is to show "Unused" columns dont show up using the mapper)

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Can I reuse code for selecting a custom DTO object for a child property with EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66378438/3744182).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77426928/3744182) shows how you can define an expression containing an external function call, then replace it with an existing function expression with the same signature.