# ASP.NET Core 6 C# Grouping Data Daily ,Monthly ,Yearly based on CreatedDate(DateTime) causing : The LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a method which get data from a SQL Server database and groups it daily, monthly and yearly.

We are dealing with a min of 3k records currently and the number increases daily based on sales.

I am trying to get the data and do the group by on database because doing GroupBy on server-memory may be good currently but later it will be very much less efficient but every time I try, I get this error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()\r\n.LeftJoin(\r\ninner: DbSet(), \r\n        outerKeySelector: b => EF.Property<int?>(b, "CreatedByBusinessCrewId"), \r\n        innerKeySelector: b0 => EF.Property<int?>(b0, "Id"), \r\n        resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<BusinessSale, BusinessCrew>(\r\n            Outer = o, \r\n            Inner = i\r\n        ))\r\n    .Where(b => b.Outer.BusinessId == __BusinessId_0 && b.Inner.BranchId == __BranchId_1)\r\n    .GroupBy(b => Invoke(__dateTruncateFunction_2, b.Outer.CreateDate.Value)\r\n    )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Here are my enums

```
public enum BusinessSalesFilteredBy
{
    Logs = 0,
    Day = 1,
    Month = 2,
    Year = 3,

}
```

Note that I am using unit of work.

Here is my code:

```
var baseQuery = _uow.BusinessSalesRepo.GetAll(sale => sale.BusinessId == BusinessId && sale.CreatedByBusinessCrew.BranchId == BranchId);

salesCount = baseQuery.Count();
clientsCount = baseQuery.Select(s=> s.ClientProfileId).Distinct().Count();
sumPurchases = baseQuery.Sum(s=> s.PurchasedAmount ?? 0);

 Func<DateTime, DateTime> dateTruncateFunction;

    switch (filterBy)
    {
        case (int)BusinessSalesFilteredBy.Day:
            groupKeySelector = sale=> sale.CreateDate.Value.Date;
            break;
        case (int)BusinessSalesFilteredBy.Month:
            groupKeySelector = sale=> new DateTime(sale.CreateDate.Value.Year,   checkin.CreateDate.Value.Month, 1);
            break;
        case (int)BusinessSalesFilteredBy.Year:
            groupKeySelector = sale=> new DateTime(sale.CreateDate.Value.Year, 1, 1);
            break;
        default:
            // Default to daily grouping
            groupKeySelector = sale=> sale.CreateDate.Value.Date;
            break;
    }

    // Now, calculate the summary data with date truncation
var summaryQuery = baseQuery
.GroupBy(sale=> dateTruncateFunction(sale.CreateDate.Value))
                        .Select(grouped => new
                        {
                            SalesOn = grouped.Key,
                            SalesCount = grouped.Count(),
                            ClientCount = grouped.Select(x =>    x.ClientProfileId).Distinct().Count(),
                            SumPurchases = grouped.Sum(x => x.PurchasedAmount ?? 0)
                        });
var pagedSummary = await summaryQuery.ToListAsync();
```

Finally here is the `GetAll()` method:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return GetAll().Where(predicate);
}

public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
}
```

My question how I can perform the entire operation on the database side without bringing the data into memory hoping of the most efficient way.

And is there no built-in thing that can help in the DateTime translation in LINQ queries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing custom Entity Framework function with IMethodCallTranslator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160320/writing-custom-entity-framework-function-with-imethodcalltranslator)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Expression<Func<,>>` to make things work on the server side. Added `DateGroupingKey`, not sure  how EF will treat `DateTime` as grouping key.

```cs
class DateGroupingKey
{
    public int Year [ get; set; ]
    public int Month [ get; set; ]
    public int Day [ get; set; ]
}
```

```cs
var baseQuery = _uow.BusinessSalesRepo
    .GetAll(sale => sale.BusinessId == BusinessId && sale.CreatedByBusinessCrew.BranchId == BranchId);


Expression<Func<DateTime, DateGroupingKey>> groupKeySelector;

switch (filterBy)
{
    case (int)BusinessSalesFilteredBy.Month:
        groupKeySelector = sale => new DateGroupingKey { 
            Year = sale.CreateDate.Value.Year, Month = sale.CreateDate.Value.Month 
        }
        break;
    case (int)BusinessSalesFilteredBy.Year:
        groupKeySelector = sale => new DateGroupingKey { 
            Year = sale.CreateDate.Value.Year 
        }
       break;
    default:
        // Default to daily grouping
        groupKeySelector = sale => new DateGroupingKey { 
            Year = sale.CreateDate.Value.Year, Month = sale.CreateDate.Value.Month, Day = sale.CreateDate.Value.Day 
        }

      break;
}

ar summaryQuery = baseQuery
    .GroupBy(groupKeySelector)
    .Select(grouped => new
    {
        SalesOn = grouped.Key,
        SalesCount = grouped.Count(),
        ClientCount = grouped.Select(x => x.ClientProfileId).Distinct().Count(),
        SumPurchases = grouped.Sum(x => x.PurchasedAmount ?? 0)
    });
var pagedSummary = await summaryQuery.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This should pretty much nail it. The main issues are that GroupBy needs an `Expression`, not a `Func` then the other gotcha in the expression would be the use of `sale.CreatedDate.Value.Date` which isn't translatable to SQL, Need to use `new DateTime(sale.CreatedDate.Value.Year, sale.CreatedDate.Value.Month, sale.CreatedDate.Value.Day)` to group by date, ignoring time.